# Simbad, NED databases surface magnitude data?

Tags: star-catalogues, simbad

I can't seem to find data about surface magnitude of galaxies in Simbad.
I can easily find the apparent and absolute magnitude ...
Should I just try to compute the surface magnitude, given the apparent magnitude, and galaxy diameter (arc sec)?
Do you know how to find surface mag in Simbad, or NED , Vizier?

Will this give a reasonable estimate?:

```
SurfaceB = m + 2.5 * log10(AngularArea)
```

Aproximate Angular Area:

```
AngularArea = pi * (galaxyDiameter/2)^2
```

Comment: The reason there is no surface magnitude is due to the difficulty in defining it. A galaxy will have a bright core, and fade out to nothing, with features of various brighness in between.

Comment: Ok, so I figure it's better to calculate a rough estimate